# FontForge: How to add a hidden personal info text

Tags: fontforge

Is there a way to add a hidden info-text in FontForge? I think, I could need that sometimes. 
I mean something like that:

[image]

Hint 1: I generate that text with a external graphic programm, not with FontForge itself; because that's my question how to do that.

Hint 2: The info text should be for own work, not for read out etc.

Hint 3: I mean info-text in the displayed area, not the comment function under 'glyph info'.

Comment: What do you want to do with the text? Do you want to read it back from some other application, do you want to actually print it when using the character, have it as a comment in your font?

Comment: While working with FontForge, creating letters, layers etc. I could need some hints, notes etc. for myself so that I know what I have done 3 years later.....

Comment: Why don't you use comments then? (Element>Glyph Info>Comment or Element>Font Info>Comment, depending on if they are on a glyph or font level)

Comment: Yes, but I asked myself whether I can add info-text in the displayed area, not the comment function under 'glyph info'. Drawing infos and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a FontForge developer, I guess the best way is to make a point with a really long name. A single floating point *shouldn't* mess anything up, especially if it's inside the bounds of the left and right bearings of the glyph.

So, go to «Point→Name Point». If you want multiline input, copy and paste from e.g. Notepad++.

[image]

I noticed that it seems to render multiple lines in the wrong place, which seems to be a minor bug (<del>I'll open a bug for it</del> done: [№4420](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/4420)), but you can just move the point up, or use multiple points floating at the right side for multiple lines.